# Global costmap update?

Tags: ros, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to know if the global costmap in the ros navigation stack updates itself or not.

I'd like to know by my question if the first created global costmap using the static map provided by map server is the same as the global costmap in the end of the navigation process when the robot reaches the destination or not.

If they're not the same, can you explain to me how it updates itself please ?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207620/global-costmap-update-!?/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The global costmap subscribes to different sensor topics over ROS and uses the sensor data to update itself. It can either insert obstacles into the costmap or clear obstacles from the costmap. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d for details.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2015-04-23**:
Thank you Naman for your answer,
I have two PCs, one situated in a robot and the other in a desktop. I'd like to publish the global costmap of the navigation stack of the robot over network to the other PC.
Can you tell if this is possible before beginning programming ?

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2015-04-23**:
Is there other possibilities to share a costmap over network ?

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-04-23**:
Yes, it is possible.. One way using ROS is to create a network with ROS Master running on one machine and other machine is using same ROS master and then you can publish or subscribe anything. Relevant links: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup, http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines